# Converting loops (Java Beginner question)

Tags: java, loops, syntax

Does Converting between loops always works like this? or there is some situation that it does not? and what is the fastest way to check while I'm solving a question like this in Exam?

For Loop:

```
 for(xx;yy;zz)
    { 
       aa
    }
```

While Loop:

```
    xx
    while(yy)
    {
      aa
      zz
    }
```

Do While:

```
      xx
      do
      { 
        aa
        zz
      }
    while(yy)
```

Comment: Do you mean `aa` instead of `yy` inside the body of the while loop?

Answer (score 8):

You have couple of mistakes. Especially `do-while` loop is incorrect since it always executes at least one iteration, which is not the case for `for` and `while` loops.

```
for(x(); y(); z())
{ 
   a();
}

x();
while(y())
{
  a();
  z();
}

x();
if(y())
{
  do
  { 
    a();
    z();
  } while(y())
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example between converting for-loop to do-while ? you are correct, I always make mistakes when it comes to Do-while.  much appreciated.

Comment: @Mohammad: There is an example of a do-while-loop in this answer, and it looks equivalent to the for-loop at the top.

Comment: I do not think that your understanding of do while is correct. A do while is guaranteed to execute the code at least once.

Comment: @Dilum Ranatunga: exactly, but the OP asked to convert given `for` loop into `do-while`. `for` loop first executes `x()` (always), then examines `y()` condition and if it evaluates to `true`, runs `a()` followed by `z()`. The exact same logic is expressed with my `do-while`. Converting given `do-while` to `for` would be interesting as well (`for` and `while` are actually very similar).

Comment: my mistake -- I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

There are some fundamental differences between a [for loop](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#For_Loop), [while loop](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#While_Loop) and [do-while loop](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#Do-While_Loop) that you should be aware of:

1) For loops are best used when you know how many times you have to loop over something. For example, when looping over an array of numbers you will need to loop over as many times as there are elements in the array.

For loop structure:

[image: For loop structure]

2) While loops are best used when you don’t know how many times you have to loop over something. For example, when reading lines of text from a file, a program will keep reading until it gets to the end of the file, without knowing beforehand how many lines it will read.

While loop structure:

[image: While loop structure]

3) Do-while loops (aka do loops) are best used when you don’t know how many times you have to loop over something AND you want to execute the loop at least once. For example, if a program continuously takes input from the user and outputs it, until the user enters the letter “q”, then you would use a do-while loop since you would need to take the user’s input at least once.

Do-while loop structure:

[image: Do-while loop structure]

Source: [Loops in Java – Ultimate Guide](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between a `for` statement and a `while` statement, or a `do-while` statement is that the `for` also specifies the initialization and the incrementation of the iterator.
For example, lets take an `Iterator` which in Java can be used to iterate through a vector or something similar (linked list for example):

```
//we already have a variable v whom type implements List interface;
for (Iterator vectorIterator = v.iterator(); vectorIterator.hasNext(); ) {
    //I left blank after the last ";" because there should come
    // the increment statement, and I need to store the .next() return value.

    int current = vectorIterator.next();
}
```

And here is the `while` version:

```
Iterator vectorIterator = v.iterator();
while (vectorIterator.hasNext()) {
    int current = vectorIterator.next();
}
```

The `do-while` is very similar to the `while` version.

I did give you this more complex example to show you that anything you do with `while`, no matter how complex, you can do with `for` either.

**EDIT**: the `do-while` statement exists as an alternative to `while`, with the only difference that the looping condition is checked at the and of an iteration. So you can make an equivalent to the example above using `do-while` like this:

```
Iterator vectorIterator = v.iterator();
if (vectorIterator.hasNext()) {
    do {
        int current = vectorIterator.next();
    } while (vectorIterator.hasNext());
}
```

but there is no purpose in doing that. You should use each tool for it's own purpose.

Comment: There's also the point that a do-while will go through its code once before performing any kind of conditional check.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me an example of Do-While because this is where I make mistakes often

Comment: The do-while you posted is perfect. You just need to bear in mind that it will go through its code once before checking to see if it should continue. So whereas 'while(false){a()}' will never run a(), 'do{a()}while(false)' will run it once.

Comment: Yeah I get this part. But let's say if the while-loop code is not going to be executed. how will I convert the same code to do-loop? I know I'm missing something silly here.

Comment: You could stick an if statement inside the do loop with the same condition as the loop itself. But that would be trying to use a hammer as a saw.

Answer (score 0):

The other members have covered the execution semantics. But I wanted to add the variable scoping semantics.

In Java, you can do this:

```
for (Iterator<String> i = localList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  String element = i.next();
  if (...) {
    i.remove();
  }
}

for (Iterator<String> i = importList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  String element = i.next();
  if (...) {
    i.remove();
  }
}
```

Where the variable 'i' is used twice.

In order to translate that to while loops with correct scoping, you need to use additional code blocks:

```
{
  Iterator<String> i = localList.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    String element = i.next();
    if (...) {
      i.remove();
    }
  }
}

{
  Iterator<String> i = importList.iterator();
  while (i.hasNext()) {
    String element = i.next();
    if (...) {
      i.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Note how the additional `{ ... }` allows you to use the same variable names.

While not as important in Java, in languages like C++, the scoping has important ramifications beyond just being able to use the same variable names. Object destruction, IIA (instantiation is acquisition) etc are affected by the additional block.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This class demonstrates the transliteration
// between while, for, and for-each loop syntax
public class LoopTest {

    // This method definition showcases do-while-loop syntax 
    public void doWhileLoop(Person[] people) {
        int i=0;
        do {
            Person p = people[i];
            System.out.println(p.getName());
            i++;
        }while(i<people.length);
    }

    // This method definition showcases while-loop syntax 
    public void whileLoop(Person[] people) {
        int i=0;
        while(i<people.length) {
            Person p = people[i];            
            System.out.println(p.getName());            
            i++;
        }
    }

    // This method definition showcases for-loop syntax    
    public void forLoop(Person[] people) {
        for(int i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
            Person p = people[i];            
            System.out.println(p.getName());             
        }
    }

    // This method definition showcases for-each-loop syntax        
    public void forEachLoop(Person[] people) {
        for(Person p : people) {
            System.out.println(p.getName()); 
        }
    }
}
```