# How do I convert this while loop to a for loop in java?

Tags: java, loops

given:

```
int counter = 10;

while (counter > 0)
{

    System.out.println(counter);
    counter = counter - 1;
}
```

So far I have:

```
for (int i = 0, i < 10, i --){

    int counter = 10
    System.out.println(counter)
}
```

I don't think that's correct but I can't quite get it. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: `for (int counter = 10, counter > 0, counter --){` - Start at `10`, while `counter` is greater then `0`, decrement `counter`

Comment: `for (int counter = 10; counter > 0; counter--) System.out.println(counter);`

Comment: @RickMeyers If you decalre a variable within a block of code that is surrounded by curly braces `{}` then the visibility scope is within that code.  So in your code, you are re-declaring `counter` for every iteration of the loop and it will always be `10`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting loops (Java Beginner question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689830/converting-loops-java-beginner-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int counter = 10; counter > 0; counter--) {
     System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Creating two integer variables is unnecessary, lets simply use counter in the loop and printing.

Comment: Please add braces; I only omitted them because it was a *comment*.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop has three parts:

- initializing the index
- testing the index
- 'stepping' the index

For the while loop these are:

- `counter = 10`
- `counter > 0`
- `counter = counter - 1`

For a for loop we have
    for (initialize, test, step) {
...
}`

So substitute the while loop parts into a for loop an you will have your answer.