# Changing loop in java

Tags: java

i have a following structure and don't know how to make it as a while loop instead of for

```
for (int X=1; X<6; X++) {
  F.put(new Posit(X,1), new Fields(new Posit(X,1)));
}
```

Comment: *Why* would you want to turn this into a `while` loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting loops (Java Beginner question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689830/converting-loops-java-beginner-question)

Answer (score 1):

```java
int count = 1;
while(count < 6) {
  F.put(new Posit(count,1), new Fields(new Posit(count, 1)));
  count++;
}
```